# jquery draggable function gets called twice

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

Any reason why this function gets called twice? Basically the script should move the container 100px to the right if it moves too far in the other direction.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( "#container" ).draggable({axis: "x", drag: function() {
      if($(this).offset().left < -100) {
        $(this).data('draggable').offset.click.left -= 100;
      }
    }
  });
});
</script>

<div id="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
</div>
```

I use jquery-latest.min and jquery-ui-1.8.14 (core, widget, mouse, draggable) for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The drag event gets called every time the drag container moves.  The event could trigger several times before the browser can redraw it the first time from your call back.

You could use the constrain option to constrain the div within a container, and/or the revert option to revert the object if it goes outside the container.